# Copy a file client server java rmi

Tags: java, rmi

I'm making a simple client-server rmi application with SSL. The code works fine, but when I copy a file that weights 58kb, it generates a copy that weights 1kb.

I'm going crazy with this. I will appreciate any help. This is the code:

**Client:**

```
package tpfinal;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.AccessException;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory;

public class Client {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Se necesitan dos argumentos: Hostname y Filename");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:\\Users\\Lucho\\workspace\\Distribuida\\bin\\keystore");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","123456");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Users\\Lucho\\workspace\\Distribuida\\bin\\truststore");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","123456");
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(null, ServerInterface.PORT, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory());

            ServerInterface server = (ServerInterface) registry.lookup("SSLServer");
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            int pos = 0;
            Respuesta respuesta = new Respuesta();
            String serverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + args[1];
            String clientCopyPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "clicopia1-" + args[1];
            String serverCopyPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "sercopia2-" + args[1];
            System.out.println(serverPath + " serverPath");
            System.out.println(clientCopyPath + " clientCopyPath");
            respuesta = server.leerArchivo(serverPath, pos, bufferSize);

            while (respuesta.getLeidos() > 0) {
                if (server.escribirArchivo(clientCopyPath, respuesta.getLeidos(), respuesta.getBuffer()) == -1) {
                    System.out.println("Se produjo un error al abrir el archivo copia1");
                }
                if (server.escribirArchivo(serverCopyPath, respuesta.getLeidos(), respuesta.getBuffer()) == -1) {
                    System.out.println("Se produjo un error al abrir el archivo copia2");
                }
                pos += respuesta.getLeidos();
                respuesta = server.leerArchivo(serverPath, pos, bufferSize);
                System.out.println(pos);
            }
            if (respuesta.getLeidos() == -1) {
                System.out.println("Se produjo un error al abrir el archivo original");
            }

        } catch (AccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Server:**

```
package tpfinal;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory;
import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory;

public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface {

    protected Server() throws RemoteException{
        super(0, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(), new SslRMIServerSocketFactory(null, null, true));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:\\Users\\Lucho\\workspace\\Distribuida\\bin\\keystore");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","123456");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Users\\Lucho\\workspace\\Distribuida\\bin\\truststore");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","123456");
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(null, ServerInterface.PORT, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory());

            Server server = new Server();
            registry.rebind("SSLServer", server);

            System.out.println("SSLServer bound in registry");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SSLServer error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Respuesta leerArchivo(String fileName, int pos, int cant)
            throws RemoteException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File archivo = new File(fileName);
        Respuesta respuesta = new Respuesta();
        respuesta.setLeidos(-1);
        respuesta.setPedidos(cant);
        if (archivo.exists() && archivo.setReadOnly()) {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(archivo);
            in.skip(pos); // Descartamos lo leído.
            respuesta.setLeidos(in.read(respuesta.getBuffer(), 0, cant));
            if (respuesta.getLeidos() == -1) {
                respuesta.setLeidos(0);             
            }
            in.close();
        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    @Override
    public int escribirArchivo(String fileName, int cant, byte[] data)
            throws RemoteException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File archivo = new File(fileName);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
        out.write(data, 0, cant);
        out.close();
        return cant;
    }
}
```

**RmiRegistry**

```
package tpfinal;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory;
import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory;

public class RmiRegistry {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Rmi Registry running on port " + ServerInterface.PORT);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:\\Users\\Lucho\\workspace\\Distribuida\\bin\\keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","123456");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Users\\Lucho\\workspace\\Distribuida\\bin\\truststore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","123456");
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(ServerInterface.PORT,new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(), new SslRMIServerSocketFactory(null, null, true));

        //Sleep
        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

}
```

ServerInterface:

```
package tpfinal;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ServerInterface extends Remote {

    int PORT = 8844;

    public Respuesta leerArchivo(String fileName, int pos, int cant) throws RemoteException, FileNotFoundException, IOException;
    public int escribirArchivo(String fileName, int cant, byte[] data) throws RemoteException, FileNotFoundException, IOException;
}
```

**Response:**

```
package tpfinal;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Respuesta implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionId = 1L;

    int pedidos;
    int leidos;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    public int getPedidos() {
        return pedidos;
    }
    public void setPedidos(int pedidos) {
        this.pedidos = pedidos;
    }
    public int getLeidos() {
        return leidos;
    }
    public void setLeidos(int leidos) {
        this.leidos = leidos;
    }
    public byte[] getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }
    public void setBuffer(byte[] buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }
}
```

The code works fine, but I'm not able to find this problem. If anyone want to try, you can remove the System.setProperty so you won't need to create keystore and truststore. Client must be executed like: java Client localhost nameOfAPicture for example: `pic.jpg`.

Comment: I nether write Java or Speak Italian(?) but are you writing the archive before you have finished reading all the data? So the writeArchive() function be after the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `escribirArchivos()` you are creating a new file, rather than appending to it. So the file is always the size of the last write to it.

Difficult to see the point of reading a file from the server and then copying it back twice.